# Prevent deleting file after switching branch

Tags: git, github

On my current branch I lost file `abc` which was in commit `fsd894qw`. I want to restore it.

```
git checkout fsd894qw
git branch -d tmp
git checkout master
git merge tmp
```

I have to fix conflict and commit

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Recovered file'
```

Why after that `abc` file is still missing?

Comment: If the file is only on branch `fsd894qw` but you merge *another* branch (namely, `tmp`) in `master`, why would you expect your file to be present in `master`? From what we see here, no link between `tmp` and `fsd894qw` whatsoever.

Comment: `fsd894qw` is commit, not branch

Comment: (only *a,b,c,d,e,f* letters in SHA-1 but whatever) and it changes nothing to the problem : `branch -d tmp` is irrelevant here, did you intend to create a `tmp` branch from `fsd894qw`? Because your `-d` parameter trumps that. It changes the branch command behaviour to a (soft) deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check out file `abc` from commit `1234abcd`¹ directly from `master`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout 1234abcd -- abc
```

Now `abc` is an untracked file in your working copy. You can `add` and `commit` it as you would any other new file.

---

¹As Romain points out in a comment, `fsd894qw` is not a valid commit hash. SHA-1 hashes are really numbers, not strings, and usually displayed in hexadecimal.